# Programas no funcionan al bloquear sesión de Windows 10

Tags: windows10, servicio, server

Os explico. Me conecto a un ordenador mediante la conexión RPD. Esto quiere decir que cuando me conecto, me pide usuario y contraseña de W10, y cuando me desconecto la sesión se bloquea, para que cuando vuelvas a conectarte te vuelva a pedir los datos de logeo.
Mi problema es que tengo 3 programas que necesito que funcionen mientras la sesión está bloqueada. 2 funcionan como servicio, pero necesitan del 3º para recoger los datos.
Los 2 programas son, uno de envío de alarmas y otro de gráficas de Tª e informes de Tª, y el 3º sería un programa desarrolado con Tia Portal, sería el WinCC y este estaría configurado como OPC DCOM. En teoría los problemas me los daría este 3º programa, porque los otros al funcionar como servicio en teoría siguen funcionando aunque bloquees la sesión, pero este no. Alguna idea de alguien que use WinCC?

Comment: Es decir que cuando cierra la sesión RDP, el 3o programa tambien cierra como si haya logado afuera (logged off?)  Si es la situación, tal vez https://superuser.com/questions/969945/windows-10-remote-desktop-session-logs-off (la segunda respuesta, en inglés) es lo que quiere.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata sobre programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. La pregunta parece encajar mejor en [su].